# Tabela intermediária de relacionamento n para n

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho duas tabelas com relação N para N no meu banco de dados, com isso, devo criar uma tabela intermediaria que possui a PK de cada uma dessas duas tabelas.

Minha duvida é: como inserir dados referenciando de forma correta as PKs na tabela intermediária?

Comment: Explique melhor qual a forma que você deseja inserir os dados, via `insert` no sql? Você já possui as PK que deseja inserir?
Detalhe melhor seu cenário, um exemplo ficaria mais claro para podermos ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar a chave primaria com a combinação das chaves das tabelas envolvidas e o restante dos campos ficar a sua necessidade.

veja o exemplo.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_x](
        [idtabelax] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [descricao] [nchar](10) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_x] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [idtabelax] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO



    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_Y](
        [idtabelaY] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [descricao] [nchar](10) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_Y] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [idtabelaY] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_intermediaria](
    [idtabelaX] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idtabelaY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [descricao] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_intermediaria] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idtabelaX] ASC,
    [idtabelaY] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_intermediaria]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table_intermediaria_Table_x] FOREIGN KEY([idtabelaX])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table_x] ([idtabelax])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_intermediaria] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Table_intermediaria_Table_x]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_intermediaria]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table_intermediaria_Table_Y] FOREIGN KEY([idtabelaY])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table_Y] ([idtabelaY])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_intermediaria] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Table_intermediaria_Table_Y]
GO
```